# Displaying UIlocalNotification badge number on top of the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilocalnotification

I am new to UILocalNotification concept.

I have a reminder button,by clicking it iam calling the UILocalNotification code......

```
-(void)LocalNotificationMethod{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate =  self.selectedDate;
    NSLog(@" self.selectedDate %@", self.selectedDate);
    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];


    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = [_titleTextFieldObj text];
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
    NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    //UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"notif %@",notificationArray);
    //[cell.textLabel setText:notif.alertBody];
    //[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[notif.fireDate description]];
    //NSDate *datee=notif.fireDate;
    //NSLog(@"notify date is %@",datee);
    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];



}
```

**iam getting the alert.But i want to display the notification badge in that reminder button.
If i got two notification then i want to get the 2badge numbers in the button.
not in the app icon...**
can anyone help me......

Comment: take a small image with rounded style and put it on top right corner of button, and take a label on that imageview and update that lable text as your badge count and hide lable and imageview both when badge count is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [CustomBadge](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge), that builds and renders custom badges using Core Graphics. They're just `UIView` subclasses, so you lay them out using their frame just like any other `UIView` subclass.

You can add `Custom badge` in your application using [CocoaPod](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/CustomBadge/2.0/index.html)